# Npx returns command not found when triggered from SSH

Tags: node.js, npm, ssh, npx

I found quite a lot of similar questions on SO, but they sadly aren't related to my issue.

I have Node installed with NVM.

```
$ node -v
v14.16.0

$ npm -v
7.7.6

$ npx -v
7.7.6
```

I'm writing a deployment script that will run git pull from our repository, then (among other things) compile the assets. If this helps, the work environment is Laravel 8, but I don't think it's related to my issue.

Running `npm install && npm run prod` while logged as the user on the distant server will work flawlessly. However running the same command via SSH returns the following:

```
jaeger@local-computer~$ ssh deploy@distant-server-with-nvm-node-npm-npx '/bin/sh -c "node -v && npm -v && npx -v && exit"'


Connecting...
v14.16.0
7.7.6
/bin/sh: 1: npx: not found
```

So... I'm lost. I've seen questions about node and/or npm being recognized, but none about npx, and I need it with Laravel mix. Of course, running the above comment from the distant service will work perfectly.

#### What I tried:

- Adding `PermitUserEnvironment yes` to /etc/ssh/sshd_config, then restarting ssh
- Installing globally npx via `npm i -g npx`, got denied by nvm, stating that npx already exists.
- Réinstalling nvm and node.
- Create a symlink between `/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/v14.16.0/bin/npx` and `/usr/local/bin`

What else can I try? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, `nvm` has installed itself in your `.bashrc`, but you're triggering a different shell (`sh`). Even if `/bin/sh` points to bash, this disables using the rcfile - see explanation below. Use `bash` directly.

Note this excerpt from bash manpage:
**--norc**

> Do not read and execute the system wide initialization file /etc/bash.bashrc and the personal initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive.  This option is on by default if the shell is invoked as sh.

This means you'll need to force bash to be run as an *interactive* shell using the flag `-i`, in addition to specifying the command via `-c`.

Comment: Holy!! Thank so much! I didn't know i needed to do that even though I knew it was possible to make it interactive!