# npm start at reboot doesn't handle destructuring operator (Beaglebone on Debian)

Tags: node.js, debian, beagleboneblack

I have a node app that runs nicely from the command line with a npm start command

But when I start it from the crontab @reboot issues the following error:

```
> pepsr@1.0.104 start /home/debian/Desktop/devel/iot
> node pepsr.js

/home/debian/Desktop/devel/iot/pepsr.js:206
                        ...config
                        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)

npm ERR! Linux 4.14.108-ti-r113
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.17.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! pepsr@1.0.104 start: `node pepsr.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pepsr@1.0.104 start script 'node pepsr.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pepsr package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node pepsr.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs pepsr
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pepsr
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/debian/Desktop/devel/iot/npm-debug.log
```

My cron tab is as follows:

```
@reboot sleep 180 && /home/debian/Desktop/devel/iot/pepsrRestartOnReboot.sh
```

pepsrRestartOnReboot.sh is as follows:

```
cd /home/debian/Desktop/devel/iot/
./pepsrStart.sh &
```

pepsrStart.sh is as follows:

```
cd /home/debian/Desktop/devel/iot/
nohup ./pepsrRestart.sh >> pepsr.log  2>&1
```

And pepsrRestart.sh is as follows:

```
npm start
```

Comment: Are you using Node.js installed globally, or `nvm` or some other version manager? I see the script is being run with Node 6.x from crontab, so it may not work. You may need to  install a newer version of Node globally, or use your version manager. See here for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66871866/6098312

Comment: You're right! I have installed node from n (12 lts) but also have npm (with 6.14). What should I keep n or npm ? Any help on removing one of those is greatly welcome

Answer (score 0):

Two version of node was installed.

What I did:

Uninstalled n:

`$ sudo n uninstall`

Installed node from the NodeSource:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -`

Actually install node 12 lts:

`sudo apt install nodejs`

Check that I have what I want:

`node -v`

`v12.22.0`